# object doesn't support property or method 'fillText' in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, html5-canvas, polyfills

I am getting the following issue in IE8. My code is working fine in Chrome, Mozilla and IE10. As IE8 doesn't support the canvas I am getting the following issue in it:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'fillText'

Here is the jQuery line which I am getting this error on:

```
context.font = basefont+"px 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, sans-serif";
context.fillText( (Math.round(parseFloat(v['value'] / totalValue * 1000 ))) /
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Use a polyfill. Google "canvas polyfill"

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Webshims](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/) which enables HTML5 and CSS3 features like semantic tags, canvas, web storage, geolocation, forms and multimedia to old versions of Internet Explorer.

Since it is based on `jQuery` and `Modernizr`, to use it you need include the dependencies `jQuery` and `Modernizr` alongside Webshims Lib:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.7.1/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/webshim/polyfiller.js"></script>
```

After that, in order to initialize Webshims and require the support for `canvas` element, you can do:

```
$.webshims.polyfill('forms canvas');
```